# Substract input in specific row from other rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this sort of data

```
  Sample Name  Type    Intensity    
1.   A           1        16        
2.   B           1        12
3.   C           1        13
4.   D           1        10
5.   Background  1        2
```

I want to subtract Intensity value of "Background" from Intensity values of Samples A,B,C and D and put the values in a new column (probably using mutate function).

In addition, when I have two different dataTypes like here:

```
   Sample Name  Type    Intensity    
1.   A           1        16        
2.   B           1        12
3.   C           1        13
4.   D           1        10
5.   Background  1        2   
6.   A           2        14
7.   B           2        12
8.   C           2        9
9.   D           2        7
10.  Background  2        3
```

I want to do the same, but subtract Background of Type 1 from Samples of Type 1 and Background of Type 2 of Samples Type 2.

So I would get something like this:

```
  Sample Name  Type    Intensity    IntensityCorrected
1.   A           1        16              14 
2.   B           1        12              10
3.   C           1        13              11
4.   D           1        10              8
5.   Background  1        2               0
6.   A           2        14              11
7.   B           2        12              9
8.   C           2        9               6
9.   D           2        7               4
10.  Background  2        3               0
```

Comment: Is "Background" always last in the group?

Comment: No, it never is actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df  =read.table(text="   Sample Name  Type    Intensity    
1.   A           1        16        
                2.   B           1        12
                3.   C           1        13
                4.   D           1        10
                5.   Background  1        2   
                6.   A           2        14
                7.   B           2        12
                8.   C           2        9
                9.   D           2        7
                10.  Background  2        3", header=T)
```

Alternative with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% group_by(Type) %>% 
mutate(Intensity.corrected = Intensity-Intensity[Name=="Background"][1])
```

Output:

```
  Sample       Name Type Intensity Intensity.corrected
1       1          A    1        16                  14
2       2          B    1        12                  10
3       3          C    1        13                  11
4       4          D    1        10                   8
5       5 Background    1         2                   0
6       6          A    2        14                  11
7       7          B    2        12                   9
8       8          C    2         9                   6
9       9          D    2         7                   4
10     10 Background    2         3                   0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! What is the meaning of [1] at the end of the line?

Comment: That means to take the first element per group where `Name=="Background"`. You could also do without in this case, but I thought it would make it a bit more robust, since if there are two backgrounds in a group it could otherwise cause some unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the OP's example, it seems that the dataset is `data.table`.  So, we use `data.table` methods.  After grouping by 'Type', get the differece of 'Intensity' with 'Intensity' wehre the 'Sample_Name' is 'Background' and assign (`:=`) it to create 'IntensityCorrected' column

```
setDT(df2) #in case it is not data.table 
df2[, IntensityCorrected := Intensity - Intensity[Sample_Name == "Background"], by = Type]
df2
#    Sample_Name Type Intensity IntensityCorrected
# 1:           A    1        16                 14
# 2:           B    1        12                 10
# 3:           C    1        13                 11
# 4:           D    1        10                  8
# 5:  Background    1         2                  0
# 6:           A    2        14                 11
# 7:           B    2        12                  9
# 8:           C    2         9                  6
# 9:           D    2         7                  4
#10:  Background    2         3                  0
```

---

With `base R`, an option would be `ave`

```
with(df2, Intensity - ave(Intensity*(Sample_Name == "Background"),
                 Type, FUN = function(x) x[x !=0]))
```